# Fancybox - How to change the content of iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, frame

I need to set or update custom HTML code in **iframe fancybox window**.
So how can I do that ?!
'content' option does not work !
Tested on localhost.

```
  $("test").fancybox({
  'width'    : 300,
  'height'   : 300,
        'autoScale'      : false,
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'content' : '<H5> It`s does not work</h5>'
 });
```

If it`s impossible to change the content of cross-domain iframe(as in my case),so,please, tell me how to do it on the same domain.
For example,we are on the **http://localhost/page1.html** and iframe links to **http://localhost/page2.html**

Answer (score 2):

When the fancybox-iframe is aleady open, you may access the iframe-element using `$('.fancybox-iframe')` .

And if the document inside the iframe is located on the same domain, you may change the contents using jQuery:

```
$('body',$('.fancybox-iframe').contents()).html('new content');
```

When the fancybox-iframe is not open yet, you may do the same inside the afterLoad-callback:

```
$("test").fancybox({
  'width'    : 300,
  'height'   : 300,
        'autoScale'      : false,
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'href':'page2.html',
        afterLoad:function(){$('body',$('.fancybox-iframe').contents())
                              .html('new content');}
 });
```

**And Yes:  it`s impossible to change the content of cross-domain iframe(you may only load a completely new document into the iframe in this case).**

Comment: Thanks for reply! Strangely,but the first variant(which I need) does not work... I just need to add few <div> or <input> tags which contain text.Spent 9 hours and nothing...

Comment: I have tryed to make  append($elem).css().html()  but it does not work too.I have used other element - fancybox-content.Yeah,element appears only if u set append(), - not css() and others.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I tried $('body',$('.fancybox-iframe').contents())
                              .html('new content'); after an ajax call returns new html and it does not change in the iframe. Do I need to something else?